# Save <td> as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hello I currently have a script where you type in an Item name into an input. along with its size, colour, and other options. It all saves as individual items with there custom specifications like so:
example t-shirt black, Large, Any size etc..

I have 3 buttons on the bottom of the table one is a input where you can name the table data then you press the add button and it adds this info as a variable where it can be called using a  inside another html file. The other is a load select where you can load up the  and edit it similar to what this GitHub file has with loading its billing info 
( https://github.com/hunterbdm/Deadass-Splash )

I also want to not only save the entire  as a variable but somehow save each line individually so I can later call it in the backend of the script where My programs nows what shirt to get along with the size and colour.

So how would I go about writing javascript(jQuery that could save the  and each line individually so I can call it later in the backend  maybe something like (variableName).line[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fNxy.png) = t-shirt black Large.

here is the html for my table:

```html
<div id="taskContainer">
  <table id="items-table">
    <!--<caption>Task</caption>-->
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th colspan="3">Options</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<label for="loadTask">Load Task:</label>
<label for="taskName">Task Name:</label>
<select id="loadTask"></select>
<input type="text" id="taskName"></input>
<button type="submit" id="addTask">Add</button>
```

How would I go about doing this? would I need to label every  so I could call [2] [2] to call each line with its special customizations? Im thinking very pythonically since Im new to Js and more experienced with python.

Here is a photo of what my table looks like:

[image]

Would I use something like ipcRenderer?

Here is also my JS how would I add some sort of counter so that I could then set the amount of lines with that number:

```
function addRow() {
    var item_text = $('#item-input').val();
    var item_color = $('#color-input').val();
    var size_text = $('#sizes-item').val();
    var any_color = $('#any-color').is(':checked') ? 'Any Color' : '';
    var any_size = $('#any-size').is(':checked') ? 'Any Size' : '';
    $('#items-table').append('<tr>'
        +'<td>'+item_text+' '+item_color+'</td>'
        +'<td>'+size_text+'</td>'
        +'<td>'+any_color+' '+any_size+'</td>'
        +'<td><button class="remove-btn"><div class="thex">X</div></button><td>'
        +'</tr>');
}
```

..

```
$(function(){
  $('#add-item').click(function(){
    addRow();
    return false;
  });
  $('body').on('click', '.remove-btn', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do this neatly with a loop but failed miserably. Anyway, so long as the number of rows you have in the table doesn't change, this will work fine.

```
var table, cell1, cell2, cell3, cell4, cell5, cell6, cell7, cell8, cell9;
table = document.getElementById("items-table");

cell1 = table.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML;
cell2 = table.rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML;
cell3 = table.rows[0].cells[2].innerHTML; // first row.

cell4 = table.rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML;
cell5 = table.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;
cell6 = table.rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML; // second row.

cell7 = table.rows[2].cells[0].innerHTML;
cell8 = table.rows[2].cells[1].innerHTML;
cell9 = table.rows[2].cells[2].innerHTML; // third row.
```

If you want to save this and use it later in another file (or the same one), you could do this easily through localStorage.

```
localStorage.setItem("cell1", cell1); // where "cell1" is the name you want to save it as and cell1 is the variable.
```

And call it later from another file with:

```
cell1 = localStorage.getItem("cell1");
```

Comment: Thank you but I have multiple things in one row how would I split the row into the Item, Size, and options?   @Intelta

Comment: I guess I could use some sort of split

Comment: is there a way I can check if it will work becuase I tried console.log(cell1); and I got this error                              
                                                                                         Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined    right at the line where the first cell is defined

Comment: I tried alert(table.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML);   and nothing happend   @Intelta

Comment: Ive also tried alert($("#items-table").cells.innerHTML);   and it still didn't work

Comment: I tested it using document.write(cell1). However I added content and several more rows in testing, so it may not work with the empty cells or ones that don't exist

Comment: Oh I see it works when I add in <td> it seems as if I will have to make it be in somekind of loop and wait until I press the submit button or something like that @Intelta